# Unable to use left outer join and using in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a SQL query in oracle and I am unable to rewrite the same in sql server. I am unable to use left outer join and using in a combination. Can some one point me in right direction.

Here's my query in oracle:

```
(select QD.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID,qi.display_number,QI.QUESTION_NUMBER,
                                qd.question_part_number
                            from FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO qi,
                                 FY_ST_QUESTION_DETAIL qd
                           where qi.region = cRegion
                             and qi.state_code = cState_Code
                             and qi.fy = nFY
                             and qi.report_id = nREPORT_ID
                             and qi.section_id = nSECTION_ID
                             and qi.subsection_id = nSUBSECTION_ID
                             and qi.display_number = nDISPLAY_NUMBER
                             and qi.QUESTION_NUMBER = nQUESTION_NUMBER
                             and ( QI.REPORTER_ID = sUSER_ID or
                                   QI.DELEGATE_ID = sUSER_ID or
                                   QI.SUB_DELEGATE_ID = sUSER_ID )
                             and QD.FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO_TABLE_ID = QI.FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO_TABLE_ID
                       )fq left outer join
                       ( select distinct FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, AD.ROW_NUMBER
                           from UPLOAD_TEMP_DATA ad
                          where ad.region = cRegion
                            and ad.state_code = cState_Code
                            and ad.fy = nFY
                            and ad.report_id = nREPORT_ID
                            and ad.section_id = nSECTION_ID
                            and ad.subsection_id = nSUBSECTION_ID
                            and ad.display_number = nDISPLAY_NUMBER
                            and ad.QUESTION_NUMBER = nQUESTION_NUMBER
                            and ad.QUESTION_PART_NUMBER = nQUESTION_PART_NUMBER
                       )aq
                     using(FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID)
              WHERE ROW_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
             order by question_number,question_part_number,row_number ;
```

Comment: This query seems wrong to me; are you sure it works in Oracle?

Comment: You should get in the habit of using the ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around for almost 30 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: IIRC, the Using thing is a way to automagically join two tables on primary keys? You can't do that in sql server. You have to explicitly name the join predicates.

Comment: where is the " ( " that should preceed " )fq left outer join "

Comment: The syntax of this query still looks wrong. `(query) LEFT OUTER JOIN (query)` isn't correct and won't execute. Please edit your question and include a query which is syntactically correct. StackOverflow is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `USING` for joins in sql server (some dbms, like mysql and Oracle for example do implement it, but... not Sql Server)

Replace it by

```
ON QD.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID = aq.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID
```

The sample code doesn't look to be a working query by the way, the `)fq` seems really weird.
The first part of the query doesn't need (and can't be) aliased.

And finally, the where clause of the main query should be placed after all joins.

Try to rewrite it to

```
    select 
      QD.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID,qi.display_number,QI.QUESTION_NUMBER,
      qd.question_part_number
    from FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO qi
    join FY_ST_QUESTION_DETAIL qd on QD.FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO_TABLE_ID = QI.FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO_TABLE_ID
    left outer join
        (select 
           distinct FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, 
           AD.ROW_NUMBER
         from UPLOAD_TEMP_DATA ad
         where 
           ad.region = cRegion
           and ad.state_code = cState_Code
           and ad.fy = nFY
           and ad.report_id = nREPORT_ID
           and ad.section_id = nSECTION_ID
           and ad.subsection_id = nSUBSECTION_ID
           and ad.display_number = nDISPLAY_NUMBER
           and ad.QUESTION_NUMBER = nQUESTION_NUMBER
           and ad.QUESTION_PART_NUMBER = nQUESTION_PART_NUMBER
        )aq
             ON QD.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID = aq.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID

       WHERE ROW_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
      and qi.region = cRegion
      and qi.state_code = cState_Code
      and qi.fy = nFY
      and qi.report_id = nREPORT_ID
      and qi.section_id = nSECTION_ID
      and qi.subsection_id = nSUBSECTION_ID
      and qi.display_number = nDISPLAY_NUMBER
      and qi.QUESTION_NUMBER = nQUESTION_NUMBER
      and ( QI.REPORTER_ID = sUSER_ID or
            QI.DELEGATE_ID = sUSER_ID or
             QI.SUB_DELEGATE_ID = sUSER_ID )
       order by question_number,question_part_number,row_number ;

Actual code:

CREATE PROCEDURE [HSIP].[PROJECTLIST_RPT1](

@cRegion CHAR(2) = '00',
@cState_Code CHAR(2) = '00',
@nFY NUMERIC(4,0) = 0,
@nREPORT_ID NUMERIC(2,0) = 0,
@nSECTION_ID NUMERIC(2,0) = 0,
@nSUBSECTION_ID NUMERIC(2,0) = 0,
@nQUESTION_NUMBER NUMERIC(38,0) = 0,
@nDISPLAY_NUMBER NUMERIC(38,0) = 0,
@nQUESTION_PART_NUMBER NUMERIC(38,0) = 0,
@sUSER_ID VARCHAR(25) = NULL,
@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID NUMERIC(38,0) = 0,
--@nrow_num integer  )
@nROW_NUMBER NUMERIC(38,0) = 0)


--coloffset integer := 17;

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

--declare @setval as varchar

declare @coloffset as integer = 17

select @nrow_number,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),1) as ProjectName,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),2) as ImprovementCategory,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),3) as SubCategory,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),4) as ProjectOutputs,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),5) as OutputType,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),6) as HsipProjectCost,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),7) as TotalProjectCost,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),8) as FundingCategory,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),9) as FunctionalClassification,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),10) as FunctionalClassificationOther,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),11) as Asdt,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),12) as Speed,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),13) as Ownership,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),14) as OwnershipOther,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),15) as RelevantShspEmphasisArea,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),16) as RelevantShspEmphasisAreaOther,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0),17) as RelevantShspStrategy,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+1) as ErrProjectName,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+2) as ErrImprovementCategory,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+3) as ErrSubCategory,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+4) as ErrProjectOutputs,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+5) as ErrOutputType,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+6) as ErrHsipProjectCost,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+7) as ErrTotalProjectCost,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+8) as ErrFundingCategory,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+9) as ErrFunctionalClassification,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+10) as ErrFunctionalClassificationOth,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+11) as ErrAsdt,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+12) as ErrSpeed,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+13) as ErrOwnership,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+14) as ErrOwnershipOther,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+15) as ErrRelevantShspEmphasisarea,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+16) as ErrRelevantShspEmphasisareaOth,

hsip.getTempResponseData(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+17) as ErrRelevantShspStrategy,

hsip.getErrorCount(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, ISNULL(@nROW_NUMBER, 0), @coloffset+17) as ValidationErrorCount,

@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, @nDISPLAY_NUMBER, @nQUESTION_NUMBER, @nQUESTION_PART_NUMBER

from
(select QD.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID,qi.display_number,QI.QUESTION_NUMBER,
                                qd.question_part_number
                            from FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO qi,
                                 FY_ST_QUESTION_DETAIL qd
                           where qi.region = @cRegion
                             and qi.state_code = @cState_Code
                             and qi.fy = @nFY
                             and qi.report_id = @nREPORT_ID
                             and qi.section_id = @nSECTION_ID
                             and qi.subsection_id = @nSUBSECTION_ID
                             and qi.display_number = @nDISPLAY_NUMBER
                             and qi.QUESTION_NUMBER = @nQUESTION_NUMBER
                             and ( QI.REPORTER_ID = @sUSER_ID or
                                   QI.DELEGATE_ID = @sUSER_ID or
                                   QI.SUB_DELEGATE_ID = @sUSER_ID )
                             and QI.FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO_TABLE_ID = QD.FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO_TABLE_ID
                       )as fq left outer join
                       ( select distinct ad.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, AD.ROW_NUMBER
                           from UPLOAD_TEMP_DATA ad
                          where ad.region = @cRegion
                            and ad.state_code = @cState_Code
                            and ad.fy = @nFY
                            and ad.report_id = @nREPORT_ID
                            and ad.section_id = @nSECTION_ID
                            and ad.subsection_id = @nSUBSECTION_ID
                            and ad.display_number = @nDISPLAY_NUMBER
                            and ad.QUESTION_NUMBER = @nQUESTION_NUMBER
                            and ad.QUESTION_PART_NUMBER = @nQUESTION_PART_NUMBER
                       ) as aq
```

Comment: @ Raphael: I tried to do it your way: go an error: The multi-part identifier "QD.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID" could not be bound.

Comment: Just tried, got this error now: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @user3147594 Is this query used to create a view ?

Comment: @ Raphael: I don't think that I am creating a view here, but I am using an inline function. Placed the actual code above. Thanks

Comment: "*Not ANSI by the way*" - that's wrong. `from a join b using (x)` **is** part of the ANSI SQL standard (and not only Oracle and MySQL support it)